# How can I securely randomize a Ruby array?

Tags: ruby, security, random

How can I use [Ruby's `Array.shuffle` method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-shuffle) with a secure random number generator?

The method can accept a random number generator as an argument. However, [`SecureRandom`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html) from the standard library is not actually a random number generator that can simply replace the [`Random`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Random.html) class.

```
a = %w(Some data that needs to be randomized)
a.shuffle! # Not securely random

# Is this any good? I arbitrarily choose 2**32. Should it be something else?
a.shuffle!(random: Random.new(SecureRandom.random_number(2**32)))
```

I did find [this example](https://coderwall.com/p/oijyja/array-sample-and-array-shuffle-using-securerandom) which simply re-implements the `Array#shuffle` method. However, I'd rather just pass in the correct random number generator into the existing (optimized) method rather than re-implementing my own.

Comment: This is not a security question, this is a programming question. But to answer it anyway, you are misreading the docs for `shuffle` (not to mention Random and SecureRandom). All you need to do is `array.shuffle(random: SecureRandom)`. `Random.new` creates a new non-cryptographic PRNG, and merely seeding it with a large cryptographically-random number does not somehow turn it into a CSPRNG.

Comment: What do you define as a secure RNG?

Comment: @schroeder by "secure RNG" I mean one that is designed to be make it difficult or cryptographically impossible to guess future random numbers. Ruby's `Random` class is a PRNG. With enough access to its output, it is at least theoretically possible to predict the numbers it will generate.